# I can't create a script on a Google Sheet that I have edit access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We are using Google Workspace in my company and my boss explicitly shared a Google Sheet with me, so he is the owner and I have edit access. I am trying to create an App Script but when I try to access the Script Editor I always get the screen to request access on Google Drive.

Is it still possible to create a script or I am only allowed to create scripts in sheets that I am the owner?

According to Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#access_to_bound_scripts) on collaborating:

> Access to bound scripts
> Only users who have permission to edit a container can run its bound script. Collaborators who have only view access cannot open the script editor, although if they make a copy of the parent file, they become the owner of the copy and will be able to see and run a copy of the script.

Comment: maybe the script is already created but restricted to the owner?

Comment: Stupid as it may seem I just found this bug: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/60481334?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I just came across this [issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/60481334?hl=en).

Essentially I had my personal account and company account logged in on Google. For some reason, the Script Editor would try and access in with my personal account and when switching to my company account I would get the request access screen.

After logging out of my personal account I was able to create the script normally.